# If I change my .gitignore file, does it change for everyone after I push the code?

Tags: git, github

I don't want certain things to be going with my PRs, so I have changed my .gitignore, but I was wondering if I change my .gitignore file, would it change for everyone after I push my code?

[This is my first internship, sorry if the question is too basic]

Comment: I don't know if this applies to you, but just FYI, .gitignore files are layered. So you can have a root level .gitignore that affects the entire repo, and you can have a .gitignore file in specific directories to additionally ignore certain kinds of files in just that directory and its subdirectories. This way you don't have to edit the root level ignore file for things that don't apply everywhere.

Comment: And not just directories but branches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about a global gitignore file outside the working tree, no.

If you are talking about a local gitignore file inside your working tree, then yes, it would work like any other file; it would affect someone else only if you push and they switch to the same branch and pull it.

Note that this will not affect any files / folders already present in the head commit.